# Google APP Script to Download TEXT file from Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The following Google Script code fetch the range of data from Google Spread sheet and download as file using the following command, The content of the file (**text.txt**) is in continuous format without delimeter or New line character at end of every Row

But I need to print the data with multiple lines as in the Google Spread sheet, How to go about this, I tried JASON.stringfy, I am unable to success

```
var cell_range_row = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
var range =sheet.getRange(1,1,cell_range_row,cell_range_column); 

var values = range.getValues(); 
var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
var txtFileName = 'test.txt';

output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
output.setContent(values);
output.downloadAsFile(txtFileName);

return output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to output the data to the text file as a new line for row by row. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

Using `join()`, the array is converted to the string. And `\n` is added for each row.

#### From :

```
var values = range.getValues();
```

#### To :

```
var values = range.getValues().map(function(e){return e.join(",") + "\n"}).join("");
```

#### Reference :

- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit

When you want to retrieve the displayed format of date. Please modify as follows.

```
var values = range.getDisplayValues().map(function(e){return e.join(",") + "\n"}).join("");
```

#### References :

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct, Thanks for your response, It work well, can you pls explain how it works

Comment: The above code var values = range.getValues().map(function(e){return e.join(",") + "\n"}).join(""); works well, I have one more query , while reading a data from a cell with Time format in the text.txt files reads as Sat Dec 30 1899 08:08:50 GMT+0530 (IST) actually the cell contains data 8.00, how to ask Google script to ready as in the same format

Comment: @Thulasi Durai I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice that the data includes the date format. This is my mistake. I'm really sorry. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Well replied, it works as I am expecting, thanks a lot

Comment: @Thulasi Durai Thank you for your response.